# UITextView delegate class crashes on clicking the textview?! What's going on?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, delegates, uitextview

So I saw this question: [How do you connect the "delegate" outlet of a UITextView to a class that implements UITextViewDelegate protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785027/how-do-you-connect-the-delegate-outlet-of-a-uitextview-to-a-class-that-implemen)

My problem is similar to what booboo is describing in the second response (not the one marked as the answer.)

I have a *MyViewController* which implements *UITextViewDelegate*. In interface builder for the nib, inside the view I have selected the TextView and assigned it's delegate to the File Owner (which is MyViewController.)

*MyViewController* has implemented

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
NSLog(@"TextView EDIT %@",textView);
}
```

Every single time I test my app though, as soon as I click on the TextView I get an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** crash. If I remove the delegate link in IB then the keyboard pops up fine.

I have also tried creating an *IBOutlet UITextView to the textview* inside MyViewController and linking the TextView to this IBOutlet in the File Owner. In the viewDidLoad then I assign:

```
myDescriptionTextField.delegate = self;
```

But this also results in the same issue of an EXC_BAD_ACCESS as soon as I click the TextView.

Inside XCODE at the top when it crashes the stack trace(i think this is what it is ?) of where it crashes says:

objc_msgSend
??

```
-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]
-[UITextView becomeFirstResponder]
-[UITextInteractionAssistant setFirstResponderIfNecessary]
```

... etc?

Does this help? I'm so lost on what this issue is? Everything seems linked correctly.

Comment: At a guess I'd say there's something broken with your connections. Can you set a breakpoint on the `viewDidLoad` method where you set the delegate to self and check if your UITextView variable has actually been initialised (i.e. it's address in memory is not 0x0)?

Comment: Show us how you initialize MyViewController, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check how the `MyViewController` object is created and managed (how you keep the object in your application). It is possible that while your `UITextView` exists as it becomes a subview of one of your `UIView` object (`addSubview` retains the subview), the `MyViewController` object itself is released from the memory after you build up your view hierarchy.

```
myDescriptionTextField.delegate = self;
```

does not retain `self`, as retaining a delegate may cause a problem of reference cycles.

Check this, and if it doesn't solve the problem try debugging with NSZombieEnabled because it will tell you where exactly you make a reference to an invalid object.

Comment: This was my issue. I released my viewcontroller object early.

Answer (score 0):

Also I got your problem!

I solve by passing weak delegate instead of self

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

than use weakSelf !!