# Detect selected tabbar when switching tab bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have three tab bar application and my tabs is TAB1, TAB2 , TAB3 i have write the following code in TAB1 view controller to detect which tab user have pressed

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item 
{ 
    NSLog(@"tab selected: %@", item.title); 
}
```

But this delegate never get called

i have setup my tab in appdelegate.m something like that

```
- (void)setupTabBar 
{
    self.myWorkListViewController = [[MyWorkListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyWorkListViewController"
                                                                               bundle:nil];
    self.askHRViewController = [[AskHRViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AskHRViewController"
                                                                     bundle:nil];

    self.moreViewController = [[MoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreViewController"
                                                                           bundle:nil];

    self.bookLeaveViewController = [[BookLeaveViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookLeaveViewController"
                                                                             bundle:nil];
    self.helpViewController = [[HelpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HelpViewController"
                                                                   bundle:nil];

    // Create navigation controllers
    workListNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myWorkListViewController];

    askHRNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.askHRViewController];

    bookLeaveViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.bookLeaveViewController];

    moreNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.moreViewController];

    helpNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.helpViewController];

    [self setTabBarImagesAndText];

    // Setup tab bar controller
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:workListNavigationController, askHRNavigationController, bookLeaveViewController, helpNavigationController,moreNavigationController, nil]];
    //Set TabBar background
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBar_iOS4_Background"]] atIndex:0];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];

}
```

Answer (score 5):

you can detect selected Tabbar Item like this way:-
as par your code you just need to add this line

```
// Setup tab bar controller
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:workListNavigationController, askHRNavigationController, bookLeaveViewController, helpNavigationController,moreNavigationController, nil]];
    //Set TabBar background
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBar_iOS4_Background"]] atIndex:0];
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

in .h file define like

```
@interface yourViewcontroller : UIViewController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
   //declare your Tabbar controller with @proparty 
}
```

in .m file

> ```
>  //@synthesize here your Tabbar controller
> ```

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  self.yourTabbarControler.delegate=self;
    [super viewDidLoad];


}
```

and  now put this delegate of UITabbarController

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"controller class: %@", NSStringFromClass([viewController class]));
    NSLog(@"controller title: %@", viewController.title);

    if (viewController == tabBarController.moreNavigationController)
    {
        tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: this delegate method also not getting called in TAB1viewcontroller :(

Comment: it work thanks :) :) but i am surprised that i have to set delegate in each controller.Cant we do this setting one time?

Comment: see this `didSelectViewController` its a delegate method of `UITabbarController` so whenever you need to use you must declare delegate's of particular UItabbarController that's why

Answer (score 0):

You have to "wire up" the delegate,  either using code (in ViewDidLoad etc.) or in interface builder.
Look at this answer which explains how to connect a textView delegate (it's pretty much the same): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785366/764575